# animationArray only playing last image

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, nsarray

I currently have this method buttonHit that calls playAnimationToNumber which accepts an int, which is then in turn used to run through a loop playing an array of images for each iteration, however it only seems to be playing the last array.. can you see why? because I am slightly lost and would appreciate the help.

```
//attached to button and it calls animation method.
- (void)buttonHit:(id)sender{
    [self playAnimationToNumber:5];
}



- (void)playAnimationToNumber:(int)number{

    for (int counter=1; counter<=number; counter++) {

        NSString *imageNameForFirstNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flap%i.png", counter];
        NSArray *imagesForAnimation = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlapMoving1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"FlapMoving2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:imageNameForFirstNumber], nil];


        animationArray.animationImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:imagesForAnimation];        

        animationArray.animationDuration = 0.5;
        animationArray.animationRepeatCount = 1;
        [animationArray startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:animationArray];



    }


    [animationArray release];
}
```

**WORKING CODE**
'
- (void)playAnimationToNumber:(int)number{

```
NSMutableArray *imagesForAnimation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];


for (int counter=1; counter<=number; counter++) {

    NSString *imageNameForFirstNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flap%i.png", counter];
    [imagesForAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlapMoving1.png"]];
    [imagesForAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlapMoving2.png"]];
    [imagesForAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameForFirstNumber]];
}
animationArray.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imagesForAnimation];        

animationArray.animationDuration = 5.9;
animationArray.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[animationArray startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:animationArray];
[imagesForAnimation release];
```

}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go try this code.

```
   - (void)playAnimationToNumber:(int)number{

    NSMutableArray *imagesForAnimation = [[[NSMutable alloc] initWithCapacity:0] autoRelease];
    [imagesForAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlapMoving1.png"]];
    [imagesForAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FlapMoving2.png"]];

        for (int counter=1; counter<=number; counter++) {

            NSString *imageNameForFirstNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Flap%i.png", counter];
            [imagesForAnimation addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameForFirstNumber]];
    }
            animationArray.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imagesForAnimation];        

            animationArray.animationDuration = 0.5;
            animationArray.animationRepeatCount = 1;
            [animationArray startAnimating];
            [self.view addSubview:animationArray];



        }
}
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thank you, only two issues were, second line
**NSMutableArray alloc** and it wouldn't let me use autorelease, so I just released the array  outside of the for loop and it worked perfectly. Thanks a bunch!.. now time to implement several animations based off one number :P fingers crossed.

Comment: Actually althought that runs through all the numbers it dosnt add the mid flips in... so the first number gets the two midflips play but then each number after that only shows the number... So it works but not how I was intending which I probably did not explain well enough.

Comment: I have added the working code to my post, you were a great help I just added the other two images into the for loop so they are played each time, not just the once, thanks.